# Python Virtualenv - Acceso denegado

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Cree un entorno virtual de Python en un servidor remoto desde mi pc mediante virtual env.
El servidor tiene instalado python y pip, y al consultar las versiones no genera problema:

```
Z:\>py --version
Python 3.10.0

Z:\>pip --version
pip 21.3.1 from C:\Users\welter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)
```

Pero cuando activo el ambiente virtual "GCPcall" e intento consultar la version de pip, me salta el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al darle ejecutar me termina denegando el acceso:

```
(GPCcall) Z:\> pip --version
Acceso denegado.
```

¿A qué se debe y como se puede solucionar?

Comment: De preferencia no uses imágenes para cubrir lo que un `bloque de código` puede hacer. En particular, te sugiero que cambies las imágenes 1 y 3 por estos bloques.

Comment: Además, nos vendría bien que nos dijeras cómo creaste el entorno virtual. ¿Qué usaste para crearlo? Ofrécenos detalles completos.